# Como salvar em CSV ou Excel uma tabela gerada a partir de outra tabela com pandas ou pivot table?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Tenho uma tabela com dados de vários anos de 2000 à 2015 no formato CSV.
No meu código eu peço o usuário para digitar um ano que ele deseja ver e retornar na tela somente os anos que ele solicitou. Ex.: 2000.

E eu quero que esses dados sejam salvos em um novo arquivo CSV(de preferência Excel) mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Quando salva, ele somente faz a cópia da tabela com outro nome.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
#enconding utf-8

import os
import platform
import pandas as pd
import pandas as to_csv
import pandas as DataFrame

plataforma = platform.system()

if (plataforma == "Windows"):
    os.system("cls")
else:
    os.system("clear")

#arquivo = open("C:\python\lista.txt", "r")
#texto = arquivo.read()

print ("\tESCOLHA UMA DAS OPÇÕES ABAIXO:\n")
print ("\tEscolha '0' para ver os dados completos.\n")
print ("\tEscolha '1' se deseja ver os dados de um ANO específico.\n")
print ("\tEscolha '2' para ver estatísticas.\n")



df = pd.read_csv("base_municipios_homicidios.csv", delimiter=";", names=["CÓDIGO MUNICÍPIO",
    "ANO","HOMICÍDIOS","IDADE MÉDIA","PROPORÇÃO NEGROS"])
#escolha = df.loc[[entrada]]
maximo = df.max()
minimo = df.min()
descricao = df.describe()
media = df.mean()

ano = int (input("Informe um ANO: "))

imprimir_ano = df.loc[(df["ANO"] == ano)]

nova_tabela = df.pivot_table(index="ANO")


print(imprimir_ano)
print (nova_tabela)

df.to_csv("vai.csv", data = imprimir_ano)

#print (df)
print("\nVALOR MÁXIMO")
print("------------\n")
print("%.f" % maximo,"\n")    
print("\nVALOR`MÍNIMO")
print("------------\n")
print(minimo,"\n")
print("\nDESCRIÇÃO")
print("------------\n")
print(descricao,"\n")
print("\nMÉDIA")
print("------------\n")
print(media,"\n")
```

Eu pensei que se eu colocasse a entrada do usuário em `df.to_csv("vai.csv", data = imprimir_ano)` eu conseguia salvar os dados, mas foi sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o modulo [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io) para exportar como arquivo do Excel, para instalar basta executar um dos comandos:

```
# Utilizando pip
pip install XlsxWriter

# Utilizando easy_install
easy_install XlsxWriter
```

Seguindo o [simples exemplo que se encontra na documentação](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_simple.html), o seu código ficará assim:

```
excel = pd.ExcelWriter('NOME_DO_ARQUIVO.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
imprimir_ano.to_excel(excel, sheet_name='Dados de um ANO específico')
excel.save()
```

veja funcionando:

[image: Exportando para Excel]

#### Código completo:

```
#enconding utf-8

import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas as to_csv
import pandas as DataFrame

print ("\tESCOLHA UMA DAS OPÇÕES ABAIXO:\n")
print ("\tEscolha '0' para ver os dados completos.\n")
print ("\tEscolha '1' se deseja ver os dados de um ANO específico.\n")
print ("\tEscolha '2' para ver estatísticas.\n")

df = pd.read_csv("lista.csv", delimiter=";", names=["CÓDIGO MUNICÍPIO","ANO","HOMICÍDIOS","IDADE MÉDIA","PROPORÇÃO NEGROS"])
maximo = df.max()
minimo = df.min()
descricao = df.describe()
media = df.mean()

ano = int (input("Informe um ANO: "))

imprimir_ano = df.loc[(df["ANO"] == ano)]
excel = pd.ExcelWriter('NOME_DO_ARQUIVO.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
imprimir_ano.to_excel(excel, sheet_name='Dados de um ANO específico')
excel.save()

nova_tabela = df.pivot_table(index="ANO")
print(imprimir_ano)
print (nova_tabela)
```